# How to fix: "/bin/bash: jar: command not found" error in Java JDK 8 manual install?

Tags: java, java-8, ubuntu-16.04

Due to dependency of another software I'm going to build, I had to install Java JDK 8 manually, I used the following guide: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-manually-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

But when I tried to build the software, the following error occurred:

```
/bin/bash: jar: command not found
```

I have set the PATH in the .bashrc and in .profile, and I also set the environment in /etc/environment but the problem still persist.

at the end of .bashrc and .profile I added the following lines:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211
JRE=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/jre
```

I expect the path location is correct and the software should build, but instead it failed. 
Please help me resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Found the solution for my problem, just have to run the following commands on the terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jar 180
```

Comment: Did you re-login (or run `source .bashrc`), so that your current PATH has that value? Does the file `jar` exist inside `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin`?

Comment: Yes, I run source ~/.bashrc and source ~/.profile, I also restarted the system. And yes, the jar exist inside /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin.

Comment: It also executes normally if you give the full path, i.e. `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jar`?

Comment: that doesn't work either. I also tried to run export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin" in the terminal, but it failed as well

Comment: It should work with the full path, regardless of PATH, so it's something else. Are the access rights OK, including the executable bit?

Comment: I run ls -l jar, the result is: -rwxr-xr-x, is that correct?

Comment: Seems correct. So what error do you get if you run `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jar` or just `./jar` in that directory?

Comment: What is the exact command you are running?

Comment: There is no error if running jar directly.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins I tried to build the so called ONOS SDN controller by using the following command: bazel build onos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem is by entering the following command on the terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jar 180
```